# Query retornando resultado divergente

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho duas tabelas:

Tabela contas com a coluna valor com dois registros totalizando 1100;
Tabela contas_receber com a coluna valor com um registro totalizando 500

Quero realizar uma query onde eu receba a soma de cada tabela, tentei algo como:

SELECT SUM(contas.valor) as totalsaidas , SUM(contas_receber.valor) as totalentradas FROM contas, contas_receber

Porém, o totalentradas que recebo da query é 1000 e não 500.
Porque isso ocorre?

Comment: Você tem que separar isso em duas *queries*. Uma pra somar o total da tabela `contas` e outra pra somar o total da `contas_receber`. Isso ocorre provavelmente por esse motivo, já que não tem relação entre as consultas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode informar mais de uma tabela na cláusula `from` sem relacioná-las de alguma maneira (usando `join` por exemplo). Dessa maneira, você precisa dos resultados separados. Pode usar um `union` por exemplo:

```
select 'Saidas',SUM(contas.valor) as Total
from contas
union
select 'Entradas',SUM(contas_receber.valor) as Total
from contas_receber
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(C.VALOR), SUM(CR.VALOR) FROM CONTAS C, CONTAS_RECEBER CR WHERE <CONDITION>
```